# Not able to pull in data from S3 into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently testing out Snowflake. We are considering building a data stack on top of Snowflake. I was trying to load a csv file in S3 into a table in Snowflake but I am getting the following error.

> Number of columns in file (10) does not match that of the corresponding table (9), use file format option error_on_column_count_mismatch=false to ignore this error File 'test.csv', line 2, character 1 Row 1 starts at line 1, column "PART"[10] If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

I have tried using the  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY attribute when creating the FILE FORMAT but no luck.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this error?

Thanks and Regards,

R

Comment: Can you show us a row (replace all char with X and all numbers with 1 if needed). Because ether you have 10 column or the formatting is wrong. And ether way we cannot guess which.

Comment: Also to help find the problem split the file into half and try load them both, if one is good and the other is not. keep repeating until you can say, "this line is happy" "this line is not happy" which ether you will see the problem, OR you can then update this question and ask a focused one.

Comment: Also, please update your question to show  the complete file format definition, the definition of the target table and the copy into command that you are, presumably, using